# Bootstrap makes margin to ul

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, margin, padding

I am wondering why Bootstrap adds an "margin" to my ul.

Without: [image: Default]

With: [image: Bootstrap as Import]

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class=""><a href="#start">CompanyX.com</a></li>

            <li class="right"><a href="#logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="#money">Hey: Peter G.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS: https://hastebin.com/uqawiwuyer.css

Hope that somebody could help me.

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: This looks like a markup issue.   Make sure you have container > row > columns and that they are immediately descending, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: You were right, thanks. I just forgot to add a row div. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually not a Bootstrap thing but default browser specific styling. Each browser adds default styles to specific elements and at least Chrome, Firefox, and Sarafi all add 40px of padding-left to all `<ul>` elements.

Not sure the reasoning behind it but a hunch is that the browser is trying to add some visual space to a list.

A [CSS normalizer](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) will resolve some of the default styling. Bootstrap already includes one but it doesn't defacto remove the ul spacing so just add the following code at the bottom at the bottom of the bootstrap.css file.

```
ul {
  margin: 0; 
  padding:0
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot Code Snippets. I added them. This was actually just a bootstrap usage mistake. Thanks of course for the serious answer.